# Synology NAS - SSHD

Tags: ssh, nas, synology

I think I did a really bad thing. I tried for several hours to get the SSH login without password working – it would not work for some reason. I changed the permissions of my home folder, added the `authorized_keys` file etc. – I read all the 100 tutorials.

I thought, hey, maybe it is just because the default `PasswordAuthentication no` option is not working. So I added it – et voila, now I can't log in anymore.

Any idea what to do? Reset the whole NAS?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular hardware, but unless it's some really cheap piece of j\*, surely it has some recovery mechanism short of an all-out factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to "Terminal and SNMP" in the control panel, disabling the SSH service (click `Apply`) and then re-enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You are completely out of luck with ssh now. Switch to telnet protocol to reverse the change and put PasswordAuthentication yes. Keep trying